# Using python fcntl.ioctl on Docker gives Errno 22

Tags: python, docker

I ran code below in latest Docker Ubuntu image, using python2:

Docker:

```
docker pull ubuntu
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

In docker:

```
apt update
apt install python
touch test
python
```

In python:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import fcntl
>>> f = open("test", "rb")
>>> binary_data = fcntl.ioctl(f, 2, struct.pack('I', 0))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The same flow I made on my PC and in the result I did not get any error.
I suspect that there is something wrong with file descriptors. In both cases when I call f.fileno() I got result 3. In both cases I run it on python 2.7.16

But when I ran in Docker:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import fcntl
>>> f = open("test", "rb")
>>> binary_data = fcntl.ioctl(2, 2, struct.pack('I', 0))
```

I got no error.

Comment: Works fine on *Ubtu 16* (*VM*).

Comment: To get more answers you can add a link to the DockerHub image you're using to run this code and copy the full error message in your question: this will help the viewers to understand your situation.

Comment: Not an expert in Python, but are you sure that your script has access to the file ? (Have you tried to connect to your container and check that out ?)

Comment: When I opened "test" file in python in container, I can write to it, so clearly this script has access.